# Cannot change color of a shape in Excel

Tags: excel, vba, colors

VBA noob here.
I am developing a workbook which makes use of an external dll from my client.
In a sheet I have a button that, when pressed, starts a routine which makes a shape orange, then calls the API and finally makes the shape black.

Misteriously, it works only 'few times'.

The following code resides in a sub within a module:

```
Dim shapeToFlash As String
shapeToFlash = "SHAPE " & sheetName
Worksheets("GTE HOME").Shapes(shapeToFlash).Fill.ForeColor.SchemeColor = 53
Worksheets("HOME").Shapes(shapeToFlash).Fill.ForeColor.SchemeColor = 53

// API CALL (kind of long operation ~ 3/4 seconds)

Worksheets("GTE HOME").Shapes(shapeToFlash).Fill.ForeColor.SchemeColor = 0
Worksheets("HOME").Shapes(shapeToFlash).Fill.ForeColor.SchemeColor = 0
```

I cannot share details about the API. I simply declare with the traditional sintax:

```
#If Win64 Then
Private Declare PtrSafe Function IMB_set_value _
    Lib "path/API.dll" () As Long

#Else
Private Declare Function IMB_set_value _
    Lib "path/API.dll" () As Long
```

and works perfectly.

The problem is that the first *SchemeColor* (to 53) does not work meaning that the API is called and the second SchemeColor too (the shape turns black). Just to test, I tried to comment the second *SchemeColor* (to 0) and I noticed that in this case the shape turns orange AFTER the API is called! That suggested me Excel create a sort of priority queue of the commands to be executed and that the API call is performed before the first *SchemeColor*: that clearly messes with my flow. Is there a way to force Excel to execute immediately an operation? Is there another reason for the fail?

P.S.: I have executed the first SchemeColor lines of code separately and works nicely so I suppose the code is correct.
P.P.S.: I have also tried using RGB instead of SchemeColor, with the same result.

Comment: When you say: **does not work**, what does that mean? your shape doesn't change the colour? Also, can you try to change the colour to a more vibrant colour.. i.e. yellow. colour you are trying to set it to is a bit dark and can be mistaken for black

Comment: The command (the first SchemeColor in the code) is totally ignored, so it does not change the color. I tried with yellow too but nothing changed

Comment: What happens if you put a `DoEvents` before and/or after the API call?

Comment: @Sam: that was my initial thought but even with `DoEvents`, updates to the shape are not applied until the end of code..

Comment: Try: `<reference to your worksheet>.Calculate` after you update the colour. What I also tried was to have a rectangle infront of the shape. This meant that I could update the transparency on the rectangle and colour of the rectangle and that worked quiet well as well

Comment: @Sam DoEvents has no success.

Comment: @Zac Calculate neither seems to works.

Comment: Can you try and add a shape to your worksheet (i.e. a square) and try the calculate with that? I'm not convinced you can fill an existing image with colour

Comment: @Zac but I do it regularly with other shapes. Moreover, if I just create a sub to color it, it works nicely

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
Sub InitiateLongRunningOperation()
    Dim Argument as String

    HighlightShape
    Argument = "Argument Value"        
    Application.OnTime Now, "'LongRunningOperation """ & Argument & """'"
End Sub

Sub HighlightShape()
    Worksheets(1).Shapes(1).Fill.ForeColor.SchemeColor = 53
End Sub

Sub LongRunningOperation(AnArgument As String)
    Debug.Print AnArgument
    ' Replace the line below with your API call
    Application.Wait Now + TimeValue("0:00:03")

    Application.OnTime Now, "ResetShape"
End Sub

Sub ResetShape()
    Worksheets(1).Shapes(1).Fill.ForeColor.SchemeColor = 0
End Sub
```

It works with `Application.OnTime` to start the chain of events without waiting for all of it to end before updating.
I have changed some of your code to make it easier to reproduce, but I think you will be able to follow it quite easy.

Comment: is there any way to specify LongRunningOperation with an argument?

Comment: I have updated the code now. It shouldn't work according to the documentation, but it does.

Comment: It seems to work!. Sorry to bother but I don't find the way to pass a string parameter instead of a parameter.

Comment: instead of a plain string*